# Navigation Mobile dropdown, make size of screen

Tags: javascript, php, css, drop-down-menu, navigation

I have a dropdown menu on my WordPress website, which displays all of the pages listed.

But I want to make this dropdown navigation fill the height of the screen.

So far, I am targeting `#main-nav-ul`
If I set a height on this, it affects the height of the dropdown.

I understand I need to be able to detect the screen size, using JavaScript, then pass this to the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 has two brand new size units: `vh` (view height) and `vw` (view width) which size elements to relative to the size of the viewport

```css
html body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

#main-nav-ul {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-nav-ul"></div>
```

[Browser support is pretty decent](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh), but if you need to support legacy browsers than the classic way to accomplish this is something like:

```js
jQuery(function(){

  var resizeTimer;
  var $win = $(window);
  
  // This is where we scale the menu
  function resizeMenu(){
    $('#main-nav-ul').height($win.height());
  }
  
  // Bind a handler so that the menu resizes when viewport size changes
  $win.resize(function() {
    // This throttles the resize 
    // Very important for performance since window resize
    // can be fired hundreds of times while changing the
    // size of the window!
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(resizeMenu, 250);
  });
  
  // Set the size of the menu initially.
  $win.trigger('resize');
});
```

```css
#main-nav-ul { background-color: blue; color: #fff; }
html body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main-nav-ul">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Note that the snippets won't actually cover the entire viewport since they run inside an iframe.